# Google Drive - change ownership of large number of files are extremely tedious/takes weeks. Any workaround?

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing, google-drive-shared-folder

I have a folder with at least 5000 files in Google Drive. I want to change ownership of both the folder and the files to another user. Changing the owner of the folder was quick and easy but didn't apply to the files in it. Instead I have to

1. scroll down again and again (because otherwise only 20 files are
   listed)
2. select a bunch of files
3. click *share*
4. change ownership
5. switch account
6. search for `pendingowner:me owner:someoneelse`
7. scroll down again and again (because otherwise only 20 files are
   listed)
8. select all files
9. click *share*
10. accept the transfer of ownership
11. remove the original users access to these files

And I can only do this for 200-300 files at the time, otherwise Google Drive chokes. And it doesn't stop there, the number of files I can change ownership on per day seem to be limited to 500-600 or so.

This is a PITA. **Is there some better way to transfer the ownership of a large number of files in Google Drive?**

I found this [tool](https://workspacetips.io/tools/change-owner/) but it only works on filetypes that are built into Google Drive (e.g. Sheets and Docs) or on GDrive/Business suite accounts.

Answer (score 0):

To select all files, use the hotkey Ctrl-A instead of your steps 1 and 2.

Free alternative: The method of cross-domain transfer with preserving file IDs using Google Shared Drives is well described [here](https://www.tabgeeks.com/tabgeeks-blog/how-to-transfer-ownership-between-domains-in-google-drive).

Summary:

1. Setup Google Shared Drive.
2. Neutralize files' ownership in the Shared Drive.
3. Assign new ownership.

If you do not have access to Google Workspace (former G Suite), you can take advantage of ready-made solutions available in the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/Transfer%20files) and also available here as a [web application](https://movefiles.app/).

Comment: What do you mean by Ctrl-A? I do that but then I need to scroll to view more files.

Comment: Shared Drive isn't for regular Google Drive accounts, is it? It's for GSuite, right?

Comment: [Ctrl-A shortcut](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2563044) for selecting all. In this case, all files are selected without having to scroll down.

Google Shared Drive is available in scope of Google Workspace only. If you don't have access to Google Workspace, try the mentioned ownership transfer utility.

Comment: Yes but Google Drive initially just lists 20 (sometimes 70 it seems) files. You have to scroll down to make it display more files.